# Is there a way to define global using directives for XAML views in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

For example in Blazor, you can define using directives in the _Imports.razor file, and they will be imported by each component of the application.
I was wondering if there is an equivalent in MAUI, for the XAML code so that you only need to write xlmns tags once such as:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

Maybe have a BaseView class and have every view inherit it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is markup that will autogenerate code at compile time, and as such is not inheritable.

But you can use `ContentPresenter` to achieve this instead.

A `ContentPresenter` can be placed in a control template to mark where content to be displayed by the templated custom control or templated page will appear. The custom control or page that consumes the control template will then define content to be displayed by the `ContentPresenter`.

You can refer to the following code:

**BasePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp821.BasePage"
             Title="BasePage">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                
                <Label Text="This is a test" />

                <!-- Content from child pages -->
                <ContentPresenter />
                
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mauiapp:BasePage 
             xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiApp821"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp821.TestPage"
            >
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Purple"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label  Text="this is the content of ChildPage"/>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</mauiapp:BasePage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage: BasePage 
{
      public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

      }
}
```

For more information, please check document [Substitute content into a ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter) .